# How can I stop a function from executing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I basically want to create a countdown for my discord ticket bot. If someone types in -close[...] the channel will be deleted after 10 seconds. But if the person who did this command types something in the channel the countdown will stop and the channel won't be deleted.

That works fine so far. But if I abort the countdown on every other message that I send to the channel the embed will be sent where it says "Countdown stopped" also if I type -close [...] again this message pops up but the channel will still be deleted after 10 seconds.

```java
function closeTicket (_ticketid, channel, deleter, reason) {
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      channel.delete();
    }, 10000);
    channel.send({embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      author: {
        name: client.user.username,
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
      },
      title: ``,
      description: "This ticket will close in 10 seconds. If this was a mistake type anything to stop the timer.",
      fields: [{
          name: "Thank you!",
          value: "Thank you for using our ticket system! Good luck and have fun playing on our servers."
        },
      ],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      footer: {
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
        text: "Support Ticket System © H4rry#6701"
      }
    }
    });
    logTicketClosed(_ticketid, deleter, reason);
    client.on('message', message => {
      if(message.channel === channel && message.author === deleter && timer != null) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
        message.channel.send({embed: {
          color: 3447003,
          author: {
            name: client.user.username,
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
          },
          title: `Timer Stopped`,
          description: "The timer has been stopped, the ticket will remain open.",
          timestamp: new Date(),
          footer: {
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
            text: "Support Ticket System © H4rry#6701"
          }
        }});
      }
    });
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Your last condition, the one that outputs the message "the timer has been stopped", checks that `timer != null` -- but where are you actually ever setting `timer` to null? I don't see it anywhere. So once you set the timer, it will never be null again, making that condition always true.

Comment: Can you please update the code in the post with what you tried, so we can see it?

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: You're checking if `timer != null` but you're setting `timer = 0`.  `null` and 0 are two different things.

Comment: I will update the code, I have also tried it with `null` but didn't work either. Sorry I'm really new to coding :D

Comment: So you're saying even after setting timer to null, the next message received triggers  a "the timer has been stopped" response from your bot? That's impossible; that response is in a condition that checks `if (timer != null)`, there's no way it would run after you set timer to null. Something else must be fishy here...

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work now! I defined a new variable called `timer_running` which would be set to `true` when the timer starts and to `false` when it stops. That way I got it to work now.

```java
  function closeTicket (_ticketid, channel, deleter, reason) {
    var timer_running = false;
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      channel.delete();
    }, 10000);
    timer_running = true;
    channel.send({embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      author: {
        name: client.user.username,
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
      },
      title: ``,
      description: "This ticket will close in 10 seconds. If this was a mistake type anything to stop the timer.",
      fields: [{
          name: "Thank you!",
          value: "Thank you for using our ticket system! Good luck and have fun playing on our servers."
        },
      ],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      footer: {
        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
        text: "Support Ticket System © H4rry#6701"
      }
    }
    });
    logTicketClosed(_ticketid, deleter, reason);
    client.on('message', message => {
      if(message.channel === channel && message.author === deleter && timer_running === true) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer_running = false;
        message.channel.send({embed: {
          color: 3447003,
          author: {
            name: client.user.username,
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
          },
          title: `Timer Stopped`,
          description: "The timer has been stopped, the ticket will remain open.",
          timestamp: new Date(),
          footer: {
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
            text: "Support Ticket System © H4rry#6701"
          }
        }});
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: This will definitely work, but you shouldn't need that extra variable, which just clutters the code.